# How to alphabetize fields in Unhide Columns dialog box in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a ton of columns in this table and I want them to be alphabetized so they are easier to find.

I remember seeing how to do this in a Youtube video but I can't find it for the life of me. Below is an example of the code I am using in multiple datasheet type forms. I'm not sure what needs to be added in to make these field lists alphabetize

`Private Sub showHideColumns_Click()
    frmInventoryListSubform.SetFocus
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUnhideColumns
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

The "columns", the controls, have both a name and, optionally, a caption.

So, in your form, you can run this code to list these:

```vb
Private Sub ListColumns()

    Dim Control As Control
    Dim Index   As Long

    For Index = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
        Set Control = Me.Controls(Index)
        If Control.ControlType <> acLabel Then
            Debug.Print Index, Control.Name, Control.Properties("DatasheetCaption").Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

May return a result like this:

```vb
 0            StipendNo     Student Number
 2            PayNo         Pay Number
 4            PayDate       
 6            PayAmount
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I'm not I understand how to get this into the unhide columns dialog box. How do you alphabetize the control list and then pass it to the unhide columns dialog box.

Comment: You could fill an array or a dictionary, sort this (browse for code), and then from this build the rowsource of the lisbox/combobox.

Comment: Do you mean create a custom control or use the built in unhide dialog box control?

Comment: A custom control. The unhide box you can't control, as far as I know.